# VBA: Design Mode triggering and interrupting Program

Tags: vba, break, mode

Has anyone encountered this issue?

The program I am running is something like this:

1. Find files in folder
2. Open document from folder
3. Read table into array
4. Loop to 2 or 1
5. Close document, set = nothing
6. Write array to spreadsheet.

In the course of my loop the documents I am opening end up triggering design mode for some reason. This causes a break in my program that exits the program, causing me to lose the progress my macro had made and start again.

Is there any way for me to avoid this happening, or to possibly understand why? I don't believe that the documents themselves are in design mode when I am opening them, just that the functionality is being triggered for some reason.

Here's the code for when I open the documents:

```
For f = LBound(strPaths) To UBound(strPaths)
    Set Files = New Collection
    dirpath = strPaths(f)
    strFile = Dir(dirpath & "*.xls*")     ' Record file into string.
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Files.Add strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    numCSV = numCSV + Files.count
    For Each strFile In Files
        dirpath = strPaths(f)
        wbkPath = dirpath & strFile
        If InStr(1, wbkPath, "Bulk") > 0 Then GoTo NextFile
        nrow = OpenDoc(wbkPath, wbkCSV)
        If Not nrow <= 1 Then
            scopeArray(k) = PullScope(wbkCSV, wshPalette, strFile, roffset, nrow, x)
            roffset = roffset + nrow
            k = 1 + k
            ReDim Preserve scopeArray(k)
        End IfNextFile:
    Next strFile
Next f

Public Function OpenDoc(wbkPath, wbkCSV As Workbook) As Long
    Dim r As Integer

' With workbook still open, process.
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wbkCSV = Workbooks.Open(wbkPath)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
  '  On Error GoTo NextDoc
    Set wshTemp = wbkCSV.Worksheets(1)

    r = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wshTemp.Columns(6)) - 1
 If r <= 1 Then
    wbkCSV.Close
    Set wbkCSV = Nothing
 End If
OpenDoc = r
End Function
```

Sincere thanks to any responses!

Comment: Do the values in `strPaths()` end with the backslash character? You seem to have left that part out of your post.

Comment: Indeed they do. Would that have some impact? The way they are formatted would be "C:\Folder\Subfolder\"

Answer (score 0):

So I figured I would provide some update for this.

I still haven't determined *exactly* what was causing this, but I think it might have been the simple fact that I was using my computer during code execution.

Adding the following line stopped the recurrence of this error:

```
Application.Interactive = False
' Code
Application.Interactive = True
```

I suspect that my addiction to refreshing web browsers with F5 was the likely culprit.